Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path on VsCoq when importing a cloned repository
Here is the arborescence of my Coq project:
├── coq-arrows-theorem
│   ...
├── _CoqProject
└── GibbardTheorem.v

The folder coq-arrows-theorem was brought with git clone https://github.com/tchajed/coq-arrows-theorem.git and installed with opam.
Here is my _CoqProject:
-Q . GibbardTheorem

GibbardTheorem.v
coq-arrows-theorem/*

My problem: in GibbardTheorem.v the line Require Import arrow. (where arrow is the name in coq-arrows-theorem's _CoqProject) is refused by VsCoq: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path arrow.

Assuming the files in coq-arrows-theorem (the library to be imported) have been compiled, that is not how _CoqProject works:

You need to add a -Q mapping (or -R, but see the difference in the refman) pointing to that project, which is the mapping you leverage in a Require in your code.

You do not add the list of files from that project, since that is rather the list of your project files to be compiled (and you don't even need to put a list there if you just want all files with extension .v to be compiled).


For more details, see in particular this section of the refman:
https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.18.0/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html#coq-configuration-basics
